# How to preview nested ScrollView from picking up refreshable modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

If I make a parent ScrollView refreshable any other nested ScrollView also will pickup the same refreshable action. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? Here is an example.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Button("Hello, world!") {
                    showSheet = true
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
        .refreshable {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `refreshable` modifier to before the `sheet` modifier:

```
.refreshable {
    print("Refreshed")
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
    ScrollView {
        ...
    }
    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
}
```

`refreshable` only modifies the things above it, so this excludes the `sheet`.

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example of how you can achieve not letting the nested have refresh actions in the code below:

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    @State private var isParentRefreshing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Button("Hello, world!") {
                    showSheet = true
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .modifier(RefreshableModifier(isRefreshing: $isParentRefreshing))
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        }
        .refreshable {
            // Parent scroll view refresh action
            // Put your refresh logic here
        }
    }
}

struct RefreshableModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isRefreshing: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    if isRefreshing {
                        ProgressView()
                            .offset(y: -geometry.size.height)
                            .padding(.bottom, -geometry.size.height)
                    }
                }
            )
            .onPreferenceChange(RefreshablePreferenceKey.self) { isRefreshing = $0 }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        if value.startLocation.y < 50 && value.translation.height > 50 {
                            isRefreshing = true
                        }
                    }
            )
    }
}

struct RefreshablePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Bool = false

    static func reduce(value: inout Bool, nextValue: () -> Bool) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the nested ScrollView to have any refresh action.

Comment: mb I changed it